# How to pass JQuery variables to Razor?

Tags: jquery, variables, razor

I have the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.LikeArea').click(function() {
        var num = parseInt(this.html());
        num++;
        elem.html(num);     
    });
});
```

Now I want to pass the jQuery variable **num** to Razor so I can update the database with the new value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a value to razor variable from javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317182/how-to-pass-a-value-to-razor-variable-from-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Razor is a view engine. Not really sure what you mean when you say that you want to pass a jQuery variable to Razor because Razor runs on the server before any javascript. You could use AJAX though to send a request to a server side template:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.LikeArea').click(function () {
        var num = parseInt(this.html());
        num++;
        elem.html(num);     
        $.ajax({
            url: '/foo.cshtml',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { num: num },
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: do something with the result returned by the 
                // foo.cshtml template
            }
        });
    });
});
```

which would send an AJAX request to the `/foo.cshtml` template in which you can fetch the variable like this:

```
@{
    var num = Request["num"];
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But I'm not really familiar with MVC. I'm using WebMatrix. Can you show me how to get the same result using WebMatrix please?

Comment: @Xoni, oh sorry, I thought you was using ASP.NET MVC. I have updated my answer to provide an example with WebPages.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov--I agree with your approach, but do you think the OP may be better off using jQuery's `.post()' instead?  It does the same thing, but might be a little more straight-forward.  Just my opinion really.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt, sure the shorthand $.post could have been used in this case.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov--Then again, if the OP is unfamiliar with jQuery, then using `.ajax()` is going too teach the parts and pieces first which is good for that individual.  Anyway, cheers!