# How to pass a value to razor variable from javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

How to pass a value to razor variable from javascript variable, is it possible asp.net mvc razor view engine?

```
@{
    int a = 0;
}

<script>
    var b = ...
    @a = b;
</script>
```

Comment: You can't. You can "pass" a Razor variable to a JavaScript variable but not the other way around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass JQuery variables to Razor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056015/how-to-pass-jquery-variables-to-razor)

Comment: And, to nit pick, they're not "jquery" variables. They're javascript variables.

Comment: @J.Steen, well, you [know](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/243591)....

Comment: @AndreiV Yes. I post it often. =)

Comment: thanks, well how to it?
`@if ($(this).width() > 100) {
    ...
}`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can't. and the reason is that they do not "live" at the same time.
The Razor variables are "Server-side variables", and they don't exist anymore after the page was sent to the "Client side".

When the server gets a request for a view, it creates the view with only HTML, CSS and JavaScript code. No C# code is left, it's all get "translated" to the client-side languages.

The JavaScript code DOES exist when the view is still on the server, but it's meaningless and will be executed by the browser only (Client side again).

This is why you can use Razor variables to change the HTML and JavaScript but not vice versa. Try to look at your page source code (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in most browsers), there will be no sign of C# code there.

In short:

1. The server gets a request.
2. The server creates or "takes" the view, then computes and translates all the C# code that was embedded in the view to CSS, JavaScript, and HTML.
3. The server returns the client-side version of the view to the browser as a response to the request. (there is no C# at this point anymore)
4. the browser renders the page and executes all the JavaScript

Answer (score 60):

But it would be possible if one were used in place of the variable in @html.Hidden field.
As in this example.

```
@Html.Hidden("myVar", 0);
```

set the field per script:

```
<script>
function setMyValue(value) {
     $('#myVar').val(value);       
}
</script>
```

I hope I can at least offer no small Workaround.

Comment: Then how you would retrieve the value stored in the Hidden field?? To pass it to an @HtmlAction("ActionName",  HiddenFieldValue) for example

Comment: quite easy, used it as follows: `@HtmlAction("ActionName", "myVar")` in HTLM a `@Html.Hidden` is equated with `<input type="hidden" value=0 id="myVar"/>`
see also [How to set and get ASP.net MVC Hidden Field values](http://forums.asp.net/t/1902490.aspx?How+to+set+and+get+ASP+net+MVC+Hidden+Field+values)

Comment: Can we access this hidden Field value in razor view? If so, how? please explain

Comment: @TharushiGeethma Yes you can. Just use JQuery selector with .val() like so: `$('#myVar').val();`

Comment: This is not changing model value

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this question is old... but I wanted to do something similar and I found a solution that works for me. Maybe it might help someone else.

I have a `List<QuestionType>` that I fill a drop down with. I want to put that selection into the `QuestionType` property on the `Question` object that I'm creating in the form. I'm using `Knockout.js` for the select binding. This sets the `self.QuestionType` knockout observable property to a `QuestionType` object when the user selects one.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm"
    data-bind="options: QuestionTypes, optionsText: 'QuestionTypeText', value: QuestionType, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

I have a hidden field that will hold this object:

```
@Html.Hidden("NewQuestion.QuestionTypeJson", Model.NewQuestion.QuestionTypeJson)
```

In the subscription for the observable, I set the hidden field to a `JSON.stringify`-ed version of the object.

```
self.QuestionType.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if (newValue !== null && newValue !== undefined) {                       
        document.getElementById('NewQuestion_QuestionTypeJson').value = JSON.stringify(newValue);
    }
});
```

In the `Question` object, I have a field called `QuestionTypeJson` that is filled when the user selects a question type. I use this field to get the `QuestionType` in the `Question` object like this:

```
public string QuestionTypeJson { get; set; }

private QuestionType _questionType = new QuestionType();
public QuestionType QuestionType
{
    get => string.IsNullOrEmpty(QuestionTypeJson) ? _questionType : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestionType>(QuestionTypeJson);
    set => _questionType = value;
}
```

So if the `QuestionTypeJson` field contains something, it will deserialize that and use it for `QuestionType`, otherwise it'll just use what is in the backing field.

I have essentially 'passed' a JavaScript object to my model without using `Razor` or an `Ajax` call. You can probably do something similar to this without using `Knockout.js`, but that's what I'm using so...

Answer (score 0):

I see that this problem was discussed some time ago, but if anyone 'll meet with this again, here is my solution:

In your *.cshtml View file:

```
<script>
var data = JsFunction("@Html.Raw(Model.Path)");
$(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var model = { Id: '@Html.Raw(Model.Id)', Data: data }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/Action",
            data: model,
            datatype: "html",
            success: function() {
                console.log('Success');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

JavaScript variable model is something that I need to pass to Razor ViewModel.
It can be done with ajax request. 
You just need to have proper argument/s in your action, that matches Json object created in JavaScript.

Hope it'll help someone!

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution that works:

in my form i use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterOrder", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", role = "form" }))
  {

   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })

   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.quantity, new { id = "quantity", Value = 0 })

  }
```

in my file.js I get the quantity from a GET request and pass the variable as follows to the form:

```
    $http({
        method: 'Get',
        url: "https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/quantity/" + usr
    })
        .success(function (data){

            setQuantity(data.number);

            function setQuantity(number) {
                $('#quantity').val(number);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Step: 1 Your Html,
First Store the value in your localstorage using javascript then add the line like below ,this is where you going to display the value in your html, my example is based on boostrap :

```
<label for="stringName" class="cols-sm-2 control-
label">@Html.Hidden("stringName", "")</label>
```

Step:2 Javascript

```
 $('#stringName').replaceWith(localStorage.getItem("itemName"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: How does this solve the original issue? Where are you capturing the values from JS and passing them to razor view?

Answer (score -1):

Yes You Can

Asp.net MVC razor

I have  2 Input

```
 <input id="TXTCount" type="number" readonly="readonly" class="form-control text-center text-bold" step="1" min="0" max="10000" value="1" inputmode="numeric" />

 <input id="TXTTOTal" type="number" readonly="readonly" class="form-control text-center text-bold" step="1" min="0" max="10000" value="1" inputmode="numeric" />
```

C# In view

```
  @{string WatsMSG = "xxx";}
```

And WhatsApp Link

```
 <a class="btn btn-success" id="WatsSendApi" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0000&text=@WatsMSG">
    <b class="text-black" style="font-size:small"> whatsapp </b><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="color:white"></i> </a>
```

And In jQuery

```
 <script>
                                        $("#WatsSendApi").click(function () {
                                            var StringMSG;
                                            StringMSG=("Ineed : ");
                                            StringMSG += (" Item Name : ");
                                            StringMSG +='@item.ITName' ;
                                            StringMSG += (" Count: ");
                                            StringMSG += $('#TXTCount').val();
                                            StringMSG += (" Price: ");
                                            StringMSG += '@item.ITPrice';
                                            StringMSG += (" Total: ");
                                            StringMSG += $('#TXTTOTal').val();
                                            alert(StringMSG);
                                            this.href = this.href.replace("xxx", StringMSG);
                                        });
                                    </script>
```

I am passing script value And Model value to C# string

Comment: How does this solve the original issue? Where are you capturing the values from JS and passing them to razor view?

Answer (score -3):

Razor View Server Side variable can be read to Client Side JavaScript using @
While
and JavaScript client side variable can read to Razor View using @: