# How To Get Selected Value When <select> </select> changed Using JS

Tags: javascript, razor

I am stuck & want to get selected the select option.

```
<select class="form-control" data-live-search="true" id="itemb">
<option data-tokens="All">All</option>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.brandCategories)
{                                    
  <option>@item.brandName</option>
}
</select>
```

```js
//search by brand name..
    $("#itemb").change(function () {
        
        var typp = document.getElementById("typ").value;
        var type = encodeURIComponent(typp);
        var brand = this.value;
        window.location.href = '/mobiles_tablets/item/?type=' + type + '&search=' + brand;
    });
```

In the above code just i get list in **@foreach** through **@viewBag** .but now I want when it return to the view it should get selected value.

please write js code?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html.DropdownListFor selected value not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476530/html-dropdownlistfor-selected-value-not-being-set)

Comment: can you provide the required answer?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code will help you to get the selected value of select element. You can modify/change it through codepen check out the below link.

https://codepen.io/uicreation/pen/KZmXbw

```js
var el = document.getElementById('yourId');
el.onchange = function(){
  console.log(this.selectedOptions[0].value);
}
```

```html
<select id="yourId">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
  <option>four</option>
  <option>five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but its not worked i did as below but not working... $(document).ready(function () {
        var el = document.getElementById('itemb');
        el.onchange = function () {
            console.log(this.selectedOptions[0].value);
        } });

Comment: i updated the question and show you the js code that onchange what i am searching which works fine, but when it get return to the view then in drobdown the searched value is not selected, please help me thanks

Comment: Hi, as i saw you want to access this.value on another location that mean after executing "window.location.href" page will reload so the "var brand" is lose his value. 
To know more hope this article will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317182/how-to-pass-a-value-to-razor-variable-from-javascript-variable

Comment: actually the scenario is that i have the view named "item.chtml" in which i have <select> where i am getting list through viewBag in foreach loop as you seen. now i want to on change of this <select> it goes to action and return to the same "item.chtml" view which working fine but the <select> value i am losting when load the view, i want to select value should be selected in the <select> so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

or if you want to get selected option index use this.

```
var el = document.getElementById('yourId');
el.onchange = function(){
  console.log(this.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but its not worked i did as below but not working... $(document).ready(function () {
        var el = document.getElementById('itemb');
        el.onchange = function () {
            console.log(this.selectedIndex);
        } });

Comment: i updated the question and show you the js code that onchange what i am searching which works fine, but when it get return to the view then in drobdown the searched value is not selected, please help me thanks