# Update Razor variable from within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a noob in using Razor and now I am trying to update a Razor variable from within a javascript function. For example:

```
@{
    bool myVariable = false;
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Foo() {
       if (some_condition)
       {
          @myVariable = true;
       }
    }

</script>

@if (myVariable)
{
   <div>
      <!-- stuff -->
   </div>
}
```

Is that possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: may be not possible, you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317182/how-to-pass-a-value-to-razor-variable-from-javascript-variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a value to razor variable from javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317182/how-to-pass-a-value-to-razor-variable-from-javascript-variable)

Comment: Are you sure the `@myVariable` is not being set?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah Yes, it helps me.

Comment: @BilalAhmed I have checked the code generated in the client side and as Abdelrahman says it is parsed as true = false, so not possible to assign a razor variable with a javascript variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@myVariable` is a server-side variable it get's it's value from server before rendering the page

`@myVariable` will print the **value** of the variable not assign to it,

so the output of `@myVariable = true;` will be

```
false = true;
```

---

**use ajax to get content from server**

```
@{
    bool myVariable = false;
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Foo() {
       if (some_condition)
       {
          $('#newContent').load('/News/GetLatest/10'); // call ajax to get content
       }
    }

</script>

   <div id="newContent">
      <!-- stuff -->
   </div>
```

---

**or you can only show the div if condition is true on the client side**

```
@{
    bool myVariable = false;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var showContent = @myVariable; // false

    function Foo() {
       if (some_condition)
       {
          showContent = true;
          $('#newContent').show(); // show it
       }
    }

</script>

   <div id="newContent" style="display: none;"> <!-- hidden by default -->
      <!-- stuff -->
   </div>
```